# How to enable mouse click sound in Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11

Windows 11 appears to have no mouse click sound. For example, when navigating in File Explorer. I am coming from Windows 7 and prefer it.

I have found instructions for choosing a Windows system sound for the event manually, but none of them say which sound to change it to. There are none named "click", or anything else that is obviously a click sound.

Answer (score 1):

If you are coming from earlier Windows version, you may be familiar with [these](https://archive.org/details/windowsxpstartup_201910) sounds.

1. Download the "Windows XP Start.wav" from the link above
2. Right click the sound/speaker icon in the bottom right taskbar and press Sound Settings
3. Click on More sound settings
4. Go on the Sounds tab and scroll down to File Explorer
5. Click on Start Navigation, browse, and find the downloaded .wav file
6. Press apply

The "click" sound should play when you press on folders and files in File Explorer.